# UIScrollview doesn't work after adding UITextfield

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a scrollview who works perfect.

but when i put a UITextfield with the interface builder in the scrollview, the scrollview doesn't scroll anymore.

any suggestions?

Comment: problem solved: autolayout was enabled

Comment: Auto Layout helped me as well. Thanks for the solution